Aquire Access token while in Private Network in Azure
I have an azure function which need to talk to Azure Synapse instance, all of them are not allowed to talk to internet. I am trying to use Managed Identity (with DefaultAzureCredential) in Azure Func to make REST api calls to Synapse. I ran into issue of not able to get access token. Is fetching token without internet feasible? If yes, please advise the steps.

you would need to allow AzureActiveDirectory service tag at the NSG level: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview#available-service-tags

If your traffic go through a firewall you would need to allow that as well.
